# Segmentation fault while performing strncpy to pointer to an array of strings C

Tags: c, string, pointers, segmentation-fault, strncpy

I am trying to copy substring of s to pointer to an array of strings. And below is my code. I have allocated the memory using malloc. But when I try to perform strncpy, I get segmentation fault. Can anyone please let me know if there is anything wrong with my code? Or is it allowed to strncpy on a array of pointers to strings

s is a string of length 32

```
char **suptr = (char **)malloc(sizeof(char *) * 11);  
if(suptr != NULL)
{
strncpy(suptr[0], s, 10);
strncpy(suptr[1], s+10, 10);
strncpy(suptr[2], s+20, 10);
strncpy(suptr[3], s+30, 2);
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: It's bad practice (an unnecessary) to cast the result of `malloc`.

Comment: What is the size of `s`?

Comment: Its 32 bit string

Comment: I mean the length of the string `s`

Comment: The length is 32

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've allocated an array of `char` pointers.  However, those pointers are uninitialized.  That is, they contain junk data and don't actually point anywhere meaningful.  So, when you try to copy data to them, you're writing to invalid addresses.

Each pointer needs to be directed to a valid section of memory first.  One easy way to accomplish this is:

```
for (int k=0; k<11; k++) {
    suptr[k] = malloc(sizeof(char)*10); // Or whatever length you want.
    if ( !suptr[k] ) {
        // handle the error
    }
}
```